# How to insert data into mongodb proper method

Tags: mongodb

What is the proper way to insert data into mongodb? I am able to see other collection by nodejs api call but if i use below method data are inserted but i am not able to see the data on my nodejs api call.

So How to resolve this isse?

Here is my data:

```
db.trade.insert([
   {
      "p_id":"ot1",
      "product_name":"Mixed",
      "product_weight":"1kg",
      "product_price":550,
      "product_image":"rose.jpg"
   },
   {
      "p_id":"ot2",
      "product_name":"Mixed",
      "product_weight":"1kg",
      "product_price":550,
      "product_image":"rose.jpg"
   },
   {
      "p_id":"ot3",
      "product_name":"Mixed",
      "product_weight":"1kg",
      "product_price":550,
      "product_image":"rose.jpg"
   }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

the `insert()` function takes a single document, while `insertMany()` takes an array of documents.

In your code, you're attempting to pass an array (multiple documents) into `insert()` (which expects a single document).

You could either make multiple calls to `insert()` or a single call to `insertMany()`.

Comment: After inserted i am not able to get the data on api call..getting empty

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you're doing that (e.g. show how you insert and then query).

Comment: i am getting data from other collection..only if i use like this insert method i amm not ble to get the data on nodejs api call

Comment: Again, please *edit your question* to show how you're trying to get the data. Without more detail in your question, it's not clear what's happening.

Comment: Edited my question